# Funcionamento da funcão fork()

Tags: c, funções, variáveis, processo

Alguém pode explicar como funciona a funcão fork() relativamente ao estado das variáveis a cada chamada ao processo filho neste pedaço de código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid,x=2;
    if (0 == (pid =fork())) {
        fork();
        pid=fork();
        if (pid==0) {
            x--;
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("aki\n");
        execl("bin/date", "date",0);
        x=x+2;
    }

    printf("x=%d\n",x);
    exit(0);
}
```

Estava a tentar perceber mas eu nao sei qual o valor que é passado para a variável do processo filho x=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função fork abre um processo filho com uma cópia dos valores das variáveis do processo pai. Nesse exemplo o `else` será executado para o processo filho e `x` irá para 4. Já no pai irá para 1.

EDIT:
Acontece que o fork quando executado abre um segundo processo e ambos os processos executam a próxima linha que está logo a seguir do fork original com isso temos o seguinte:

Acontece o primeiro `fork` no `if` onde é feita uma atribuição para a variável `pid`. O resultado disso é 0 que na condição de teste está ok e entra no bloco. A primeira linha desse bloco é um `fork` que não atribui nada a `pid`, com isso temos um processo filho que ***não*** entra no `else` e começa a executar na próxima linha que é um outro `fork` atribuindo a `pid`. Mas logo em seguida o processo pai desse segundo filho também executa o `fork` atribuindo ao `pid`. Como um desses é o pai vai atribuir 0 a `pid` equanto o outro não diminui a variável `x`.

Com isso temos: 
pid=45750x=2 filho de um fork dentro do if
pid=45751x=2 filho de um fork do outro filho dentro do if
pid=0x=1 pai original
pid=0x=1 filho do original e pai do segundo fork dentro do if

No processo filho do original entra no `else` que faz o `x=x+2;` esse imprime `pid=45748x=4`.

Comment: o que nao percebo é ,o que é carregado para as variáveis nas outros 2 fork()

Comment: @user48571 Você já [executou o código](https://ideone.com/pNx6xp) pra ver os valores das variáveis?

Comment: no minha maquina retorna aki
pid=45748x=4
pid=45750x=2
pid=45751x=2
pid=0x=1
pid=0x=1

Comment: @user48571 Agora com a saída adicionei mais explicações

Comment: quando eu faço uma chamada ao fork, o que é executado no processo filho também inclui um novo fork() no processo filho?

Comment: Sim porque você só colocou o if testando o resultado no primeiro. Nos outros fez a chamada sozinha e eles também funcionam.